# Escape from <script> to cause a XSS (XSS when reflection is already under <script>)

Tags: passwords, authentication, web-application, xss, exploit

I am trying my level best to solve [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/67856/running-javascript-when-there-is-error-on-the-script/) issue i am totally not able to create a XSS i still thinks it to be a vulnerability and i think it is exploitable. I am frustrated around it for 8 days . Please help me solve this issue and don't mark it as duplicate (because it is the same question) and only one great person has tried to answer it.

Thank you....

Comment: "don't mark it as duplicate (because it is the same question)" It is the same question, why shouldn't it be marked as a duplicate? Are you asking for more answers? The answer given is pretty thorough, as well as the comments following.

Comment: shelvacu i agree with you its a duplicate but 1 people replied and in past 2 days it has gone down in the list and if you mark it as duplicate no 0ne will even bother to answer. I dont marked the given answer as answer because despite of the efforts and help from gentle man @bobince i was not able to generate a XSS (you are in a hurry to mark it as duplicate instead of that try to find a solution)

Comment: @user38257 That's not how StackExchange works. If you didn't get an answer to your question, it's probably because you didn't provide enough information or detail. Editing your question or commenting on it brings it back to the active questions list, where people are more likely to see it. Do not repost old questions.

Comment: @Polynomial: Comments don't reactivate it, just edits. user38257: Once you have enough rep you can offer a bounty for a good answer.

Comment: i will keep this in mind next time

Answer (score 0):

if you can have execution without the last two fields, I'd try something like that

```
'};alert('xxx');var misc={aa='bb
```

otherwise if they are required, just add them before closing the first dict

Comment: it is the perfect example of creativity man,after custmizing your given script a bit like `' };alert(13);var misc={a:b` it worked but at the begining of the script a single `'` is ruining all.. Every varient of it is sanitized.. But great answer man thankyou